# R ROWMAX Based On Criteria

Tags: r, max, row

```
data=data.frame("id"=c(1,2,3,4),
"score1"=c(1,1,2,1),
"score2"=c(1,2,3,3),
"score3"=c(2,3,1,1),
"score4"=c(3,4,4,2),
"score1WANT"=c(1,1,2,1),
"score2WANT"=c(1,2,3,3),
"score3WANT"=c(2,3,3,3),
"score4WANT"=c(3,4,4,3))
```

Here there are four possible scoring options: 1,2,3,4.

If any 'score' equals to 3 then all subsequent scores equals to 3 UNLESS there is a 4. So as example: 1 3 2 2 should be change to 1 3 3 3 . 3 2 3 4 should be change to 3 3 3 4.

I try to do this with ROWMAX but the problem is that there is a 4 and so then it sets values to 4 if there is a 4.

Comment: Do you need as separate columns with 'WANT" suffix or update the original ones

Comment: What if the score for an id is 1, 2, 1, 1? Would you want any scores changed for that id?

Comment: If 1,2,1,1 it can stay this way. Only modification is that if ever there is a score equals to 3 it stays that way unless it is a 4.

Comment: what about if there are values like 5 or 6

Comment: @akrun there would not be since it goes from 1 to 4

Comment: it is really good thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need `cummax` and assuming this needs to be general

```
data[2:5] <- t(apply(data[2:5], 1, cummax))
```

---

If the condition is only for value 3

```
data[2:5] <- t(apply(data[2:5], 1, function(x) {
      i1 <- which(x == 3)
      i2 <- which(x == 4)
     if(length(i2) > 0) replace(x, i1:(i2-1), 3) else replace(x, i1:length(x), 3)}))
```

Comment: i tried this but then it takes 1,2,1,3 and turns it into 1,2,2,3 but I only want to do such a thing for the value of '3'. Does this make sense

Comment: is there a way to do cummax where it only applies to certain values? so 1,2,1,3 stays 1,2,1,3 but 1,2,3,1 goes to 1,2,3,3.